# User control simple data binding - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have an Address User control.

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend><%#Title%></legend>
<div>
<div>Country</div>
    <div><uc:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" /></div>
</div>


<div>
<div>City</div>    
    <div><uc:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" /></div>
</div>


<div>
<div>Street</div>     
    <div><uc:TextBox ID="txtStreet" runat="server"/></div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

And CodeBehind

```
private BEAddress _address;
    public BEAddress Address
    {

        get
        {
            if (CoordinatesVisible)
            {
                _address = new BEAddress()
                {
                    Country = txtCountry.Text,
                    City = txtCity.Text,
                    Street = txtStreet.Text,
                    Block = txtBlock.Text,
                    Building = txtBuilding.Text,

                    Latitude = txtLatitude.Text,
                    Longitude = txtLongitude.Text
                };
            }
            else
            {
                _address = new BEAddress()
                {
                    Country = txtCountry.Text,
                    City = txtCity.Text,
                    Street = txtStreet.Text,
                    Block = txtBlock.Text,
                    Building = txtBuilding.Text

                };
            }
            return _address;
        }


        set
        {
            if (CoordinatesVisible)
            {
                _address = new BEAddress()
                {
                    Country = value.Country,
                    City = value.City,
                    Street = value.Street,
                    Block = value.Block,
                    Building = value.Building,

                    Latitude = value.Latitude,
                    Longitude = value.Longitude
                };
            }
            else
            {
                _address = new BEAddress()
                {
                    Country = value.Country,
                    City = value.City,
                    Street = value.Street,
                    Block = value.Block,
                    Building = value.Building,

                    Latitude = value.Latitude,
                    Longitude = value.Longitude
                };
            }
        }

    }
```

How do I do simple data binding? I want to something like this

```
<uc:Address runat="server" ID="uc1" Address=<%#GetAddress %> />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing out of the box in ASP.NET unless you want to use the [DetailsView](http://www.learn-asp.net/ASPTutorials/DetailsView.aspx) which I don't like at all.

For my programs I wrote a own class that manages the binding for me in a generic way.
The idea behind was to bind a control property to a object property.